# How to sum data on one row from multiple selected Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I am tracking paid advertising key performing metrics on both Google & Facebook ads platforms on two separate Google Sheets, however, I'd like to combine both datas collected into one master sheet. So far, here's what I have gotten:

`={IMPORTRANGE( "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kOm1N64gZ08WHCWBH0wXnm0phGxmTxeWf_U4ovLrwUU/edit#gid=1811166264", "Oct 2023!B2:AQ2"); IMPORTRANGE( "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18eLmAq-E-qIIHursMhZKIuJz-5vGsNcwhR6yjRdQnGM/edit#gid=1397524782", "Oct 2023!B2:AQ2")}`

The issue I'm running into now is that it is creating two separate rows in my Master Google sheet, when in reality I need the data summed together inside of 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum()` instead of an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276), like this:

```
=sum( 
  importrange("1kOm1N64gZ08WHCWBH0wXnm0phGxmTxeWf_U4ovLrwUU", "Oct 2023!B2:AQ2"); 
  importrange("18eLmAq-E-qIIHursMhZKIuJz-5vGsNcwhR6yjRdQnGM", "Oct 2023!B2:AQ2") 
)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! 

My only other question would be how do you keep all the same data and automatically continue on the following row without having to manually change each cell? I attempted to highlight and drop to the following row with my cursor and it doesn't change the data value, I want it to change for example on Row 2 - "Oct 2023!B2:AQ2" to Row 3 - "Oct 2023!B3:AQ3"...

Comment: @alphex111 Comments should be used to ask for clarification and to provide suggestions to improve a post. When someone answer the question, the appropriate way to thanks is to accept the answer and when it is possible to answer the question that the answerer might have. If you have a follow-up question, it should be posted as a new question.